# Wp_customize_image_control Use Add Media

Tags: theme-development

Is there a way to use the Add Media in the wp_customize_image_control for Theme Customizations? The default image_control is very bare bones and only allows uploading of an image. There's no selection from the library or editing options.

Comment: Not sure if it can be implemented in thedefault image control, for sure in a custom control. Read the official documentation, try to do it yourself and come back if you need help.